# Компилятор выдает ошибку

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.

1. Не подскажите, где можно скачать или посмотреть оригинальную документацию по библиотеке java, для того чтобы её можно было выучить (классы, методы и как их правильно применять).
2. Добавляю `import.io.*;`, чтобы воспользоваться методом `cons.readLine();`. Компилятор не пропускает ни `cons.readLine`, ни `cons.printf("Введите имя")`, ни `int c = System.in.read();`, выдает ошибку, подчеркивает красной линией `cons` и `System.in.read()`.

Не знаете, где в моих действиях ошибка? Среда разработки Eclipse.

```
package имя;
import java.io.*;

public class класс {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    System.out.println("Hallo World");

    cons.printf("Введите имя");

    String name = cons.readLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: Просто комментарий автору вопроса: Java - язык строгий. В большинстве своем строгий к использованию оперативной памяти, потому надо переменные объявлять и типизировать всегда.

Answer (score 1):

[[@Александр1111](/users/26897/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%801111)](/users/26897/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%801111), действительно, почитайте документацию
(а сначала какой-нибудь учебник).

В http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html (первая же ссылка в гугле по запросу "java read") пишут, что `.read()`

```
Throws:
   IOException - if an I/O error occurs.
```

Значит либо его надо заключить в блок `try { ... } catch (IOException e)  { ... }`, либо просто добавить слова throws Exception после main (...)

(думаю, в любой книжке по Java все это подробно растолковывают).

Answer (score 1):

@Александр1111: System.console().readLine()? Ну или курите этот ответ, если в вашем IDE System.console() даёт null.

Comment: Как я понял, в самоучителе опечатка, в коде пропущена операция создания объекта класса Console с именем cons.
За ответ спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

1. Попробуйте вбить в гугле магическое заклинание "java документация". Понимаю, что трудно, но уверяю вас, найдете много нового и интересного
2. Что такое cons и откуда вы его взяли? Подозреваю, что именно этим вопросом задается и ваш компилятор

**Обновление**

> cons я взял из самоучителя по jave в качестве примера ввода данных с клавиатуры

Я объясню свою мысль чуть более подробно. Вы нигде не объявили этот ваш cons. Вполне логично, что ваш компилятор знать не знает, что это такое (я кстати тоже). Вы же не станете говорить компилятору "Ну блин, чувак, этот cons я взял из самоучителя по Java, а ему можно верить"

Comment: cons я взял из самоучителя по jave в качестве примера ввода данных с клавиатуры, как правильно пользоваться методом readLine?
Магическое заклинание  работает много нового, не там искал.

Comment: >cons я взял из самоучителя по jave в качестве примера ввода данных с клавиатуры

я объясню свою мысль чуть более подробно. Вы нигде не объявили этот ваш cons. Вполне логично, что ваш компилятор знать не знает, что это такое (я кстати тоже). Вы же не станете говорить компилятору "Ну блин, чувак, этот cons я взял из самоучителя по Java, а ему можно верить"